# Fortran MPI status error

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am getting the following error on compiling the following code

Code:

```
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
      include 'common_files.inc'
      CHARACTER*100 MNO, MESSAGE
      integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

        call MPI_INIT(ierror)
        call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
        call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)      
        starttime = MPI_WTIME()
        /* ........rest of code.................
```

Compilation output:

main.f:23.46:

```
      integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)          
                                              1
Error: Variable 'mpi_status_size' cannot appear in the expression at (1)
main.f:23.62:

      integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)          
                                                              1
Error: The module or main program array 'status' at (1) must have constant shape
```

The 'common_files.inc'  file contains the header files like 'include 'mpif.h''.   Unfortunately I am not allowed to post the remaining code.

I am compiling the above using the following command

```
mpif90 -g main.f
```

What could be the possible reasons for the error?.

Comment: Dont start new questions with the same content! If you need a new question with a similar topic, you should explain how the new one differs and why you didn't just edit the old one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425067/fortran-mpi-init-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have an issue with the `include 'mpif.h'` statement:

See for example:

```
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
c      include 'mpif.h'
      integer rank, size, ierror, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

        call MPI_INIT(ierror)
        call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
        call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)      
        print *, size, "  ", rank
        call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
      end
```

gives me:

```
$ mpif90 foo.f
foo.f:4.46:

      integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)          
                                              1
Error: Variable 'mpi_status_size' cannot appear in the expression at (1)
foo.f:4.62:

      integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)          
                                                              1
Error: The module or main program array 'status' at (1) must have constant shape
```

Whereas if I uncomment the `include 'mpif.h'` line, it just compiles and works.

You should double-check your `common_files.inc` file.